# When using ACF Flexible Content, how can I add an outer wrapper

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF Pro to make a page builder or at least the notion of one. I have added a series of components to my flexible content field and then I render them in a loop like so:

```
{{--
  Template Name: Page Builder
--}}
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    {{-- @include('components.page-builder.header') --}}
    <section class="section-content">
        {{-- 
            Loop through the layouts and render the appropriate blade file. 
            Note that our layouts use underscores and our Blade files use hyphens.
            E.g. layout news_block references news-block.blade.php.
        --}}
        @if (have_rows('page_builder_elements'))
            @while (have_rows('page_builder_elements'))
                @php
                    the_row();
                    $layout = str_replace('_', '-', get_row_layout());
                @endphp

                @include('layouts.page-builder.' . $layout)
            @endwhile
        @endif

        {{-- @php
            $fields = get_fields();  
        @endphp

        <ul>
            @foreach ($fields as $name => $value)
                <li><b>{{ $name }}</b> - {{ var_dump($value) }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul> --}}
    </section>
@endsection
```

My question is, if I wanted to allow a user to add a containing section such as if they wanted to add a background image across multiple components, how would I do this?